# $\sum_na_n$ converges. Prove that $\sum_n(a_n)^2$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

I know that someone has already asked a very similar question, but I don't understand the hint that was given and would really appreciate some more explanation.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent.  Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n)^2$ converges.  We are also given that $a_n \gt 0$ for all n $\in \Bbb N$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If $a_n > 0$ converges, then $a_n \to 0^+$. Use this, to show that $a_n^2 < a_n$ beyond some $N$ and conclude what you want.

Comment: You won this time. *Covers gunshot. Walks away.*

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Lol!

Answer (score 1):

Since $a_n \to 0$, $a_n$ is bounded by some constant $B$. Then $0 \le\sum_n a_n^2 \le B \sum_n a_n$.